# R integration to Tableau loop problems

Tags: r, tableau-api

I have been using R as my main programming language for quite some time now and I am just new to Tableau. I have this code written below:

```
SCRIPT_STR(
'
    data<-read.csv("Final Odds Drop Result Binded.csv",header=TRUE)

    for(i in 1:length(data$betInfoMember)){
        if(.arg1==data$col1[i] && .arg2==data$col2[i]) && .arg3==data$col3[i]) && .arg4==data$col4[i] && .arg5==data$col5){
            index<-i
        }
    }

    timeGroup<-paste(data$col1[index],"-",data$col2[index],"-",data$col3[index],"-",data$col4[index],"-",data$col5[index])

',ATTR([matchInfo matchid]),ATTR([Ticketinfo Wagertype]),ATTR([Ticketinfo Selection]),ATTR([Ticketinfo Handicap]),ATTR([Ticketinfo Bettime (copy)])
)
```

For illustration purposes, I have written a similar result below:

```
col1       col2        col3 col4       col5 
Boston     Celtics     2008 Pierce     Paul   Boston-Celtics-2008-Bryant-Kobe
Los Angeles Lakers     2009 Bryant     Kobe   Los Angeles-Lakers-2009-Nowitzki-Dirk
Los Angeles Lakers     2010 Bryant     Kobe   Los Angeles-Lakers-2009-Nowitzki-Dirk
Dallas      Mavericks  2011 Nowitzki   Dirk   Dallas-Mavericks-2011-Bryant-Kobe
```

The result should have the same value with the columns but the result were just different. The goal of this code is to run an external data outside Tableau by loading the data through R and running a loop until the conditions are met and returning a single value to Tableau. But it seems that the conditions are not perfectly met. Any help with this will do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data, so I am not able to reproduce the issue.  But upon first glance, you are retaining the string in timevalue when you must return it.  Replace

```
timeGroup<-paste(data$col1[index],"-",data$col2[index],"-",data$col3[index],"-",data$col4[index],"-",data$col5[index])
```

with

```
paste(data$col1[index],"-",data$col2[index],"-",data$col3[index],"-",data$col4[index],"-",data$col5[index])
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried your suggestion and it still doesn't work. I have tried to play with the Compute using function of Tableau but still, I get wrong results.